# Data type mismatch in criteria expression SQL Select In Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rrs As Recordset
Dim strselect As String
Set db = CurrentDb
strselect = "SELECT [Stok Pembelian] FROM t_databarang WHERE [ID Barang]= '" & Me.Text7 & "'"
Set rrs = db.OpenRecordset(strselect)
Me.Label1.Caption = rrs![Stok Pembelian]
```

I have a project from my school. I'm beginers and i'm so confused about my Access. I think that code it's correct, but there's an error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." I already search much articles about how tow to fix it but not found. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is most likely a number, thus no quotes:

```
strselect = "SELECT [Stok Pembelian] FROM t_databarang WHERE [ID Barang]= " & Me!Text7.Value & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the textbox value into a double or int...

```
Dim Text7a as Double

Text7a = CLng(Me.Text7) 'Beware of rounding with Long Integers
```

Now use the alias `Text7a` for:

```
strselect = "SELECT [Stok Pembelian] FROM t_databarang WHERE [ID Barang]= '" & Me.Text7a & "'"
```

Comment: Sorry. I answered above.

Comment: @Gustav what are you sorry for I don't get you? Did you downvote this before or something?

Comment: Yes. You declared a _Double_, assigned it a _Long_ - then concatenated the value as a _string_ exactly as in the question which, of course, still will raise the _data type mismatch_ error.

Answer (score -1):

Check  data types!
Like "Long Text do not match Number data type." Do it both them same data type on your database design